# Find a constant $c$, such that $f(x)\leq cx^2$ for every $x\geq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> For 
>   $$f(x):=\log(e^x+e^{-x})$$ and
>   $$f'(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$$
>   Can we find a constant $c$, such that $f(x)\leq cx^2$ for every $x\geq 0$?

Clearly, $f'(0)=0$. It seems we need to have a bound on $f''$.

Based on the some answers, $f(x)\leq x^2$ for $x>1$. But what I want to get is about $x\geq 0$. Is there any new bound for 
$$f(x)\leq c x^n+\log 2,$$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: Should the derivative be reciprocal of what you wrote here?

Comment: Sorry, I modify it.

Comment: @AnasA.Ibrahim this is plus not minus.

Comment: The answer is no, but I can't get the proof

Comment: @AnasA.Ibrahim No? But there are two answers...

Comment: Well, I tried graphing it on Desmos, and couldn't find such $c$

Comment: If you plug in $x=0, f(0) > RHS$,

Comment: @Alex, yes that pretty much solves it xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the inequality $ \cosh(x) \leq e^{x^2/2} $, which gives $ \log(e^x+e^{-x}) \leq \log 2 + x^2/2 $.

Comment: what is the domain of $x$?

Comment: Any real number.

Comment: So how to get this inequality from the $\cosh(x)\leq e^{x^2/2}$?

Comment: Taylor expansion: $ e^x + e^{-x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k+(-x)^k}{k!} = 2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!} \leq 2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x/2)^{2k}}{k!} = 2e^{x^2/2} $, where the penultimate inequality follows from $ (2k)! \geq 4^k k! $.

Answer (score 2):

At $x=0$ LHS > RHS $\forall c$, so your problem can't be solved. Instead, you can find for which $c$ LHS>RHS $\forall x>x_0$ for some $x_0$

Comment: Thanks. How to get a polynomial bound on $f(x)\leq cx^{n}$ for $x\geq 0$?

Comment: em... how about $f(x)\leq cx^2+\log 2$ for $x\geq 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $f(0) \leq g(0)$ and $f'(x) < g'(x)$ for all $x > 0$, then $f(x) < g(x)$. In other words try looking for $c$ such that

$$f'(x) < 2c x$$

You can use (or prove) that $\tanh x < x$ for positive $x$

Comment: So it seemts $c=1$?